# AngularJS updates variable in a different file without being instructed to do so

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my JS on home.js:

```
angular.module("HomeApp", ["BaseApp"])
    .controller("MainCtrl", ["$http", "$window", "BaseService", function($http, $window, BaseService) {

        var self = this;

        BaseService.fetch.postsX(function(posts, cerrorMessages) {
            // I need to have the line below or else self.posts
            // won't be updated (it would just be left blank).
            self.posts = posts;
            self.cerrorMessages = cerrorMessages;
        });

        self.like = function(id, postType) {
            BaseService.like(id, postType, function(posts) {
                // No need for self.posts = posts;
                console.log(self.posts);
            });
        };
```

And this is base.js (BaseApp):

```
angular.module("BaseApp", [])
    .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    }])

    .config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }])

    .factory("BaseService", ["$http", "$window", function($http, $window) {
        var self = this;
        self.posts = {};
        self.obj = {};


        /* When you call accessErrors, you must provide a callback which
         * sets cerrorMessages on the front-end (cerrorMessages will be
         * provided as a parameter to the callback). */
        self.obj.accessErrors = function(data, callback) {
             var cerrorMessages = [];
             for (prop in data) {
                 if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                     if (data[prop] != null && data[prop].constructor ==  Object) {
                         self.obj.accessErrors(data[prop]);
                     }
                     else {
                         cerrorMessages.push(data[prop]);
                     }
                 }
             }
             callback(cerrorMessages);
         };


        /* When you call fetch.postsY or fetch.postsX, you Must provide
         * a callback function which sets self.posts and self.cerrorMessages
         * on the front-end (posts and cerrorMessages will be provided as
         * a parameter to the callback). */
        self.obj.fetch = {
             postsY: function(callback) {
                 $http.get('/postsY/')
                 .then(function(response) {
                     self.posts = response.data;
                     callback(self.posts);
                 }, function(response) {
                     self.obj.accessErrors(response.data, function(cerrorMessages) {
                         callback(self.posts, cerrorMessages);
                     });
                 });
             },

             postsX: function(callback) {
                 $http.get('/postsX/')
                 .then(function(response) {
                     self.posts = response.data;
                     callback(self.posts);
                 }, function(response) {
                     self.obj.accessErrors(response.data, function(cerrorMessages) {
                         callback(self.posts, cerrorMessages);
                     });
                 });
             }
         };

        /* When you call like, you need to have a callback function
         * which sets self.posts and self.cerrorMessages on the front-end.
         * self.posts and cerrorMessages will be passed as parameters to the
         * front-end). */
        self.obj.like = function(id, postType, callback) {
            $http.post("/" + postType + "/" + id + "/like/")
            .then(function(response) {
                angular.forEach(self.posts, function(post, index, obj) {
                    if (post.id == id) {
                        post.likes.push('currentUser');
                        post.liked=true;
                    };
                });
                callback();
            }, function(response) {
                 self.obj.accessErrors(response.data, function(cerrorMessages) {
                     callback(self.posts, cerrorMessages);
                 });
            });
        };

        return self.obj;
    }]);
```

The weird thing is, when I initially load home.html which loads home.js, I need to do `self.posts = posts` after I do `BaseService.fetch.posts`, or else the posts won't appear on home.html (even though in base.js, `posts` is updated). However, when I like a post (calling `self.like`), I don't need to do `self.posts = posts` in the `self.like` function (look at the comment I have in the `self.like()` function to help understand what I mean). Even without doing it, home.html updates `posts` and `post.liked` equals `true` and `post.likes` has `currentUser` in it.

How come AngularJS updates `posts` in home.js in the latter situation even without me explicitly telling it to do so after `self.like()` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically because `self` is different in each case.

#### Why it doesn't seem to propagate?

On the `home.js`, `self` is the controller's instance which is what the view has access to.

On `base.js`, `self` is the factory's instance so it's not the controller itself.

#### But why doesn't the same happen on like?

The reason the same doesn't apply on `like`, is cause when fetch the posts on your factory, you store a reference on the Factory (`self.posts`) and you return that same reference to the controller via Promise:

```
$http.get('/postsY/')
.then(function(response) {
   self.posts = response.data;
   callback(self.posts);
}, function(response) {
   self.obj.accessErrors(response.data, function(cerrorMessages) {
       callback(self.posts, cerrorMessages);
   });
});
```

Hence, effectively both references are the **same**. When you change the post on the `like` function on the factory, you reference to `self.posts` again and since both have the same references, the update appears to be propagated but in fact, you're using a **single object** being referenced in two places.

You can test this by changing `self.posts` on your factory to something else, such as `self.foo` and returning it the same way you're doing it.

Since you're returning `self.obj` on the Factory, you don't have access to the `posts` since the bare structure is like this:

```
self = {
  posts: [], // all your posts
  obj: {} // all your methods
}
```

You could attach `posts` to `obj` (or flatten the whole object into a single level) and return it and you could do this on your controller:

```
self.getPosts = function () {
  return BaseService.posts;
};
```

In that way you don't *need* to store anything in your controller.

Comment: Just to clarify, (1) when you say "You can test this by changing self.posts on your factory to something else, such as self.foo and returning it the same way you're doing it": If I change `self.posts` on my factory to `self.foo` and return `self.foo`, and then if I like an object, wouldn't AngularJS not even loop through the `forEach` function becuase `self.post` is empty? and (2) When you say "Since you're returning self.obj on the Factory, you don't have access to the posts since the bare structure is like this", don't I have access to posts by calling `self.posts` from inside `self.obj`?

Comment: (1) Exactly, you would need to change all references inside your factory to be `self.foo` instead of `self.posts` but that was sort of an exercise to illustrate that not because they share a name they are the same. (2) Yes, if you're inside `self.obj` you have access since the closure allows that. What I mean is you don't have access to `self.posts` (being that on the Factory) **outside** of said Factory.

Comment: When I do `BaseService.fetch.drops(function(posts, cerrorMessages) { console.log(BaseService.posts); });` it logs "undefined". I tried using the `self.getPosts` function which you provided and it says that `BaseService.posts` is "undefined". Any idea why?

Comment: You need to change a lot of things before you are able to access `BaseService.posts` get rid of the `obj` part and store things on `self` on the Factory and when you return `self.obj` just return `self`. That should do the trick.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. I just did that and `BaseService.posts` does get logged correctly now. However, This is my home.js: `self.getPosts = function() { return BaseService.posts; }; self.posts = self.getPosts(); BaseService.fetch.postsX(function() {});` however, even after linking `self.posts` to `BaseService.posts`, when I do `BaseService.fetch.postsX` (which changes `BaseServicel.posts`), my home.js `posts` does not get updated. I have to manually do `self.posts = self.getPosts();` inside `BaseService.fetch.postsX` again.

Comment: Shouldn't I not need to manually do it since I already linked `posts` to `BaseService.posts`?

Comment: You can find the answer to my questions above in this post (see the answer provided by Claies): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33882994/angularjs-binding-two-variables-together-without-being-told-to-do-so