# AngularJS binding two variables together without being told to do so

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my Controller (`home.js`):

```
angular.module("HomeApp", ["BaseApp"])
    .controller("MainCtrl", ["$http", "$window", "BaseService", function($http, $window, BaseService) {

        var self = this;

        self.posts = BaseService.posts;

        BaseService.fetch.postsY(function() {
            self.posts = BaseService.posts;
        });

        self.like = function(id, postType) {
            BaseService.like(id, postType, function() {
                console.log(self.posts);
            });
        };
    }]);
```

This is BaseService (`base.js`):

```
angular.module("BaseApp", [])
    .factory("BaseService", ["$http", "$window", function($http, $window) {
        var self = this;
        self.posts = {};
        self.cerrorMessages = [];

        self.fetch = {
             postsY: function(callback) {
                 $http.get('/postsY/')
                 .then(function(response) {
                     self.posts = response.data;
                     callback();
                 }, function(response) {
                     // Do something with the error.
                 });
             }
         };

        self.like = function(id, postType, callback) {
            $http.post("/" + postType + "/" + id + "/like/")
            .then(function(response) {
                angular.forEach(self.posts, function(post, index, obj) {
                    if (post.id == id) {
                        post.usersVoted.push('voted');
                        post.voted=true;
                    };
                callback();
                });
            }, function(response) {
                 // Do something with the error.
            });
        };

        return self;
    }]);
```

When I load `home.html` (which loads `home.js`), the posts are loaded successfully (because in the callback for `BaseService.fetch.postsY()` I do `self.posts = BaseService.posts` after fetching and changing `BaseService.posts`. The weird thing is, after I like a post (which calls `self.like`), `self.posts` gets updated on `home.html` automatically, even without me doing `self.posts = BaseService.posts` in the callback for `self.like` (when I log `self.posts` on `home.html` in the callback for `self.like`, I can see that `post.voted=true`). Why does AngularJS automatically update `self.posts` in `home.html` without me doing `self.posts = BaseService.posts` in the callback for `self.like`?

According to the answer by @AntonioLaguna in this post: [AngularJS updates variable in a different file without being instructed to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850792/angularjs-updates-variable-in-a-different-file-without-being-instructed-to-do-so)

it is becuase I am binding `self.posts` to `BaseService.posts` when I do `BaseService.fetch.postsY()`, however, if I change `BaseService.fetch.postsY()` to this:

```
        BaseService.fetch.postsY(function() {
            // Do nothing in the callback.
        });
```

then `self.posts` on my controller remains empty even after fetching the posts (even though I binded `self.posts` on my controller in the line before by doing:

```
self.posts = BaseService.posts;
```

With that said, how come calling `self.like()` automatically updates `self.posts` on my controller even though calling `BaseService.fetch.postsY()` with an empty callback function does not (considering that I already binded `self.posts` to `BaseService.posts` at the beginning of my controller)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of `BaseService.posts`, you are first assigning it to an empty object and then assigning it to an entirely different object (`response.data`), which is presumably an array, in the `postsY` function.  The controller will still have a reference to the empty object, and have no idea that the object has been replaced by the service with an array.

In the case of `self.like()`, That function is merely iterating through the existing array of `posts` and modifying the *properties* of the objects.  If the controller is properly pointing to the array of objects, since the array itself isn't being removed and replaced, the controller will be pointing to the same instance of all the objects in the array in memory, and changes to these object's properties will be reflected.

Comment: Hm, is there any way I can make AngularJS update `BaseService.posts` after successfully calling `BaseService.fetch.postsY()` (rather than assigning it to a new object by doing `self.posts = response.data`)?

Comment: you might try initializing `self.posts` as an array `[]` instead of an object `{}`;  beyond that, you can try iterating through the `response.data` and pushing the server objects into an established array, but this can get strange if you fetch the same data more than once....

Comment: I tried initializing `self.posts` as an array `[]` by doing `self.posts = [];` in my BaseService but that did not solve the issue unfortunately. And yea, I can see how pushing the server objects into the array can cause issues in the long run. I guess I'll just keep doing `self.posts = BaseService.posts;` in the callback of my controller function after every server call which fetches posts. Thanks for the help!

Comment: also, using `$resource` or one of the many libraries, like [restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular), can really simplify some of these common tasks.